# Apache rewrite rule with parameters?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following URL:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?m=feedback&cSubject=My Subject
```

I want to have a rewrite rule so that the following:

```
http://domain.com/feedback?Subject=My Subject
```

maps to the previous url. Heres my rule at the moment:

```
RewriteRule ^feedback?Subject=(.*)$ index.php?m=feedback&cSubject=$1
```

Doesn't seem to be working tho! Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Query Strings are not parsed by Apache Mod_Rewrite, but there is a workaround. Try this

```
RewriteRule ^feedback/?$ index.php?m=feedback&c%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Comment: That's what I was missing for my dynamic search queries. Thanks, Clops!

Comment: how would you get rid of the necessary `?` at the end? it doesn't work if i just remove it

Answer (score 7):

You can use RewriteCond statement to do exactly what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Subject=(.*)
RewriteRule ^feedback$ index.php?m=feedback&cSubject=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an = missing from clops answer to give..

```
RewriteRule ^feedback/?$ index.php?m=feedback&c=%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

.. at least I need one to make it work.